# A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception. DB Mail can't send email

Tags: sql-server-2012, dbmail

My db mail suddenly stopped working, the error is:

> The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail
> server failure. (Sending Mail using Account 2 (2018-08-14T16:00:23).
> Exception Message: Cannot send mails to mail server. (A call to SSPI
> failed, see inner exception.).

I can't find any more info on the error, it just suddenly stopped working.

My SQL Server is 2012.

All my smtp settings are correct and nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

If it worked at one point and you haven't changed anything with your firewall, then check your email password. Also if you are using gmail - you need to check if 'lesssecure' is turned on.

Open your Google Admin console (admin.google.com).
Click Security > Basic settings .
Under Less secure apps, select Go to settings for less secure apps .
In the subwindow, select the Enforce access to less secure apps for all users radio button. ...
Click the Save button.